# Count the occurence of specific combinations of characters in a list

Tags: r, count, combinations

My question is very simple..but I cant manage to work it out...
I have run a variable selection method in R on 2000 genes using  1000 iterations and in each iteration I got a combination of genes. I would like to count the number of times each combination of genes occurs in R.
For example I have

```
# for iteration 1
genes[1] "a" "b" "c"
# for iteration 2
genes[2] "a" "b"
# for iteration 3
genes[3] "a" "c"
# for iteration 4
genes [4] "a" "b"
```

and this would give me

```
"a" "b" "c"  1
"a" "b"      2
"a"  "c"     1
```

I have unlisted the list and got the number each gene comes but I am interested in is the combination. I tried to create a table but I have unequal length for each gene vector. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I could immediately think of is to `paste` them and then use `table` as follows:

```
genes_p <- sapply(my_genes, paste, collapse=";")
freq <- as.data.frame(table(genes_p))
#    Var1 Freq
# 1   a;b    2
# 2 a;b;c    1
# 3     c    1
```

The above solution assumes that the genes are sorted by names and the same gene id doesn't occur more than once within an element of the list. If you want to account for both, then:

```
# sort genes before pasting
genes_p <- sapply(my_genes, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=";"))

# sort + unique
genes_p <- sapply(my_genes, function(x) paste(sort(unique(x)), collapse=";"))
```

---

**Edit:** Following OP's question in comment, the idea is to get all combinations of 2'ers (so to say), wherever possible and then take the table. First I'll break down the code and write them separate for understanding. Then I'll group them together to get a one-liner.

```
# you first want all possible combinations of length 2 here
# that is, if vector is:
v <- c("a", "b", "c")
combn(v, 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  "a"  "b" 
# [2,] "b"  "c"  "c"
```

This gives all the combinations taken 2 at a time. Now, you can just paste it similarly. `combn` also allows function argument.

```
combn(v, 2, function(y) paste(y, collapse=";"))
# [1] "a;b" "a;c" "b;c"
```

So, for each set of genes in your list, you can do the same by wrapping this around a `sapply` as follows:

```
sapply(my_genes, function(x) combn(x, min(length(x), 2), function(y) 
                                      paste(y, collapse=";")))
```

The `min(length(x), 2)` is required because some of your gene list can be just 1 gene.

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "a;b" "a;c" "b;c"

# [[2]]
# [1] "a;b"

# [[3]]
# [1] "c"

# [[4]]
# [1] "a;b"
```

Now, you can `unlist` this to get a `vector` and then use `table` to get frequency:

```
table(unlist(sapply(l, function(x) combn(x, min(length(x), 2), function(y) 
                                           paste(y, collapse=";")))))

# a;b a;c b;c   c 
#   3   1   1   1
```

You can wrap this in turn with `as.data.frame(.)` to get a `data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(sapply(l, function(x) combn(x, min(length(x), 2), 
                     function(y) paste(y, collapse=";"))))))

#   Var1 Freq
# 1  a;b    3
# 2  a;c    1
# 3  b;c    1
# 4    c    1
```

Comment: Perhaps also `sort`ing if order is not important

Comment: Hi, thank you so much thats great- thats what I wanted! Can I ask one more question? How could I also find all possible combinations? i.e. in the above example "a" "b" appears 3 times; once as "a" "b" "c" and twice as "a" "b". Can I do this in R for all possible genes? million thanks again